# InkScape starts extremely slow

Tags: performance, inkscape

InkScape starts extremely slow on a powerful machine (16GB RAM, Intel Core i7, SSD).

I did:

```
$ inkscape
```

After 8 seconds the window appears. This happens every time I start `inkscape`.

Is this a known behavior? Or is it a feature that can be disabled? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more fonts to load the longer it takes to start.

I got a 1 time sample from this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/418726/comments/11):

> With 405 fonts installed:
>
> $ time inkscape
>
> real 0m14.972s  user 0m11.833s  sys  0m0.192s
>
> With 2148 fonts installed:
>
> $ time inkscape
>
> real 0m42.716s  user 0m41.919s  sys  0m0.140s
>
> I got the number of installed fonts from "fc-list : file".

Mind though we had some progress on it according to [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/488247/comments/47):

> Comment 47 for bug 488247 ~suv (suv-lp) wrote on 2014-11-07:  #47
>   Improved launch times (0.91) based on
>   - new icon cache on disk (John A. Cruz)(r9969)
>   - font loading speed-up (Liam P. White, Tavmjong Bah)(r13523, r13617)

We use 0.48. Latest is 0.48.5 (found on inkscape website). [0.91 is Inkscape Next Release](https://inkscape.org/en/develop/next-release/) so you might take a plunge and try the developer versions.

[Developer edition can be found here](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/trunk).

---

Confirmed in chat: 0.91 starts up within a second and the slow start of 0.48 was due to lots of google fonts.

---

[0.91 got released today](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/inkscape-091-released-with-new-renderer.html) with a new renderer and 700+ bugfixes. From the link:

> Inkscape 0.91 includes significant performance improvements thanks to a new Cairo-based renderer which is faster on most drawings. Also, the rendering of SVG drawings is now cached, resulting in important responsiveness improvements.
>
> Furthermore, the latest Inkscape uses OpenMP multithreading for filters (filters use all available processor cores for computation), which provides better performance when editing drawings that include large filtered objects on multi-core systems.

[Official release notes](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.91).

Installation using the Inkscape PPA stable version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Answer (score 0):

During Inkscape startup it loads icons and fonts.

Start-up time improved with version 0.91, but there is still a delay, especially if you have lots of installed fonts.

Other applications (like GIMP for example) also have a load process which can be slow, but they have a splash dialog that shows the loading progress.  Inkscape doesn't have this.  The user experience could be improved if Inkscape had a loading/splash screen to indicate what's happening.